# Laravel : How do I fetch just the eager-loaded element and put them all in an array?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two models-ConversationsUser and Events-which are related in a many2many relationship. I want to eager load Events and put it all in an array. How do I do that?

---

These are my models and their relationships.

**ConversationsUser**

```
public function events(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Events');
}
```

**Events**

```
public function conversations(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('ConversationsUser');
}
```

**Controller (what I have done so far)**

```
    $loginuser = Auth::user();
    $convUsers = ConversationsUser::with('Events')->where('user_id','LIKE',$loginuser->id)
                 ->has('events');
    $events = $convUsers->get()->fetch('events')->toJson();
```

**unwanted result**

```
[
   [
      {
        "event_id":3
        "conversaitons_id":1
      }
   ],
   [
      {
        "event_id":5,
        "conversations_id":23
      },
      {
        "event_id":6,
        "conversations_id":23
      }
   ]
]
```

**Preferred result**

```
[
      {
        "event_id":3
        "conversations_id":1
      },
      {
        "event_id":5,
        "conversations_id":23
      },
      {
        "event_id":6,
        "conversations_id":23
      }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to do it the other way around, like this:

```
$conversation_ids = ConversationsUser::whereUserId($loginuser->id)->get(['conversations_id'])->toArray();
$events = Events::whereIn('conversations_id', $conversation_ids);
```

Comment: This is the way to go.

Comment: I too thought of doing this way as my last resort if I can't make use of the many2many relationship. Btw, I would do `ConversationsUser::whereUserId($loginuser->id)->lists('conversations_id')`.

Comment: btw, please replace `Event` with `Events` because they are two very different classes : One is Laravel's default class, another one is the custom-made class.